# Change shown username and hostname in terminal emulator

Tags: terminal

I am usong Sony Xperia Z3 6603 with latest available android. When using the Terminal Emulator, by default, the shown username@device is some random jibberish@D6603. Copy below:

`u0_a218@6603`

I have fiddled around with the hostnames, since one was localhost and the other one was the wi-fi random generated one. Its the one in net.hostname and the /proc/sys/kernel/hostname, i havent touched the /etc/hosts since i think it will break something. I havent touched either build.prop for the same reason, i dont really know what depends on the ro.product.device. $PS1 gives different output than the shown username.

The question is, which values are safe for editing, and which one should be edited for the shown username?

Comment: The username is the UID of the terminal emulator app (not something one can change); the hostname is the device codename defined in `build.prop` (changing it affects all apps that detect device identity according to it).

Comment: Thanks, i couldn't find information for some reason. Also, after i rebooted, proc/sys/kernel/hostname returned to localhost for some reason. Does it require unlocked bootloader or something? And what is meant by affecting all apps?

Comment: @AndyYan I beg to differ. The info shown by the terminal, plus a couple of custom functions, is defined inside `/system/etc/mkshrc`). To edit it, you need root privileges.

Comment: Hmm, I didn't trace deep enough, just trying to tell where the defaults are from. Now that I've read further on that (a related SE question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22625910/customize-adb-prompt)), it's looking good for what OP actually intends to ask (you should probably post an answer). Just one additional question: how about differentiating between root an non-root? I don't have good Linux knowledge so I can't see which element in the default `PS1` string corresponds to that.

Comment: `
if (( USER_ID )); then PS1='$'; else PS1='#'; fi
PS4='[$EPOCHREALTIME] '; PS1='${|
 local e=$?

 (( e )) && REPLY+="$e|"

 return $e
}$USER@$HOSTNAME:${PWD:-?} '"$PS1 "

`   Thats the content i think i will have to edit. Question is, is it save (wont corrupt anything) and will it persist after reboot (in case of locked bootloader).